# How to remove punctuation and special characters from in Python 3.x using .maketrans() and .unicodedata()?

Tags: python, pandas, punctuation

I want to remove all punctuation and special characters from a csv file using maketrans() and unicodedata() is as follows. But I don't understand the results.

I need that the output be a DataFrame just without the punctuation and special characters.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
```

```
names = pd.read_csv('datasets/sample_names.csv', sep='+')
names = names.rename(columns=dict(Nome='fullname'))
names.head()
```

```
import unicodedata2 as unicode
import stringt
```

```
def normalizing_text(text_normalize):

    nfkd_form = unicode.normalize('NFKD', str(text_normalize))
    non_accented_name = "".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicode.combining(c)])

    return str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys([*string.punctuation, *string.digits]))

names = names.apply(normalizing_text)
names
```

The output is:
fullname    {33: None, 34: None, 35: None, 36: None, 37: N...
dtype: object

Answer (score 0):

You could use str.replace() on each column you need to perform this on:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name' : ['He,nry.', 'Jody.', 'F,ran/', 'Adam*']}) 

   Name
0  He,nry.
1  Jody.
2  F,ran/
3  Adam*

df.Name.str.replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")

Output:

0    Henry
1     Jody
2     Fran
3     Adam
```